# How to parse from string with tag in it tag name and its arguments in Qt?

Tags: xml, string, qt, parsing, tags

Say we have a QString with next contents: `<tag attr1="string" attr2=34 />` how to make Qt parse this tag as usual xml (not using QtWebKit) tag say having sring object get tag name, value `string` of `attr1` and value `int` of `attr2`?

Comment: For parsing XML, use QXmlStreamReader or QDomDocument. Note that the '34' in your example must be quoted to be valid.

Comment: Do you really need to parse this almost-XML but non-XML text? The `attr2=32` isn't XML but you say you want to get it parsed as an integer rather than as a string, so adding the quotation marks before parsing as XML doesn't help, since it wouldn't be distinguishable from `attr2="32"` (a string with contents `32`). You'd need to write your own XML parser or do more complicated hacking to parse this using an XML parser (like adding "string:" after the first quotation marks and *afterwards* quotation marks around unquoted attribute values).

Comment: Creating a data format that looks _almost_ like XML and then writing a new parser for that should be forbidden by law :) Format should be changed to proper XML, then read either by QXmlStreamReader or by QDomDocument. After that it is very easy to convert some strings to ints.